# gwt add custom widget to panel

Tags: gwt, widget

I have created some classes in which it create a bunch of widgets (e.g. label, textbox). I want to create the widget on the fly and add it to a panel. How can I do that.

Comment: Is your class extend Composite or any other container? If so dont forget to call initWidget. Can you post your code

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you use [HorizontalPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HorizontalPanel.html), [VerticalPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html), [FlowPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html) or some other panel with an [add(Wiget)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HorizontalPanel.html#add(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget)) method, you would simply invoke `add(myWidget);`

```
final VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();

final Button sendButton = new Button("Add widget");
panel.add(sendButton);
sendButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        panel.add(new Label(new Date().toString()));
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

An alternative may be use the [setVisible(boolean)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setVisible(boolean)) to show and hide widgets instead of adding and removing them.

```
final VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();

final Button sendButton = new Button("Toggle visibility");
panel.add(sendButton);

final Label label = new Label(new Date().toString());
panel.add(label);

sendButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        label.setVisible(!label.isVisible());
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```